# NoMethodError in Users#show error?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I log in my user from the rails login screen, it successfully tries to redirect me to the user's profile page upon verifying the login credentials, however, for some reason I receive this error upon landing on the profile page (**show.html.erb)**:

> **NoMethodError in Users#show** <%= @user.email %> in show.html.erb

I'm not sure why, as the email field is not nil in my database? I search the user in the rails console to verify this:

```
 => #<User id: 11, firstname: "Leila", lastname: "Law", email: "leila@gmail.com", created_at: "2016-01-24 19:49:13", updated_at: "2016-01-24 19:49:13", password_digest: "$2a$10$WDTN0YlUr3W/zNfAhymZzuKvZiQL1praJowYtkK3v.6...", password: nil>
```

See my code below - thank you!

**show.html.erb**

```
<setheading>Personal Information</setheading>

<%= @user.email %>
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
   class SessionsController < ApplicationController


  def new
  end

  def create


   @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)

   if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])

     session[:user_id] = @user.id



    # log_in user
     redirect_to @user

   else

   #  flash[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination' #Not quite right!
     render 'new'

     end
  end

def destroy
end
end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    flash[:success] = "You signed up successfully"
    flash[:color] = "valid"
    redirect_to @user
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Form is invalid"
    flash[:color] = "invalid"
    render "new"
  end
end



private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
end


def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def new
end

end
```

**Schema.db**

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "firstname"
    t.string   "lastname"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "password"
  end
```

**Console result when login attempted:**

```
>  Started POST "/login" for 96.49.105.234 at 2016-01-24 19:50:40 +0000
>     Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
>       Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"JYAY6VQi6FOuPsZXmLhfVjIcBtC0DLrwKY+9SKBAhgmfb+0rOKWsWGK9s+YSTHZTtuTK6LUVpxExX2Y2mHlW0A==",
> "session"=>{"email"=>"leila@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"},
> "commit"=>"Log in"}
>       User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT 1  [["email", "leila@gmail.com"]]
>     Redirected to users/11
>     Completed 302 Found in 118ms (ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

Comment: Can you include your users controller? especially the show method of the users controller

Comment: I think you have a syntax error in your question that is not causing the error:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@user` is not assigned in the controller. You should change

```
 user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
```

to

```
 @user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
```

You'll have to update all the occurrences of user in the controller. Also notice the extra space here

```
params[:session][:email] .downcase
```

It should be

```
params[:session][:email].downcase
```

Moreover, if the session value was never set before, your controller will crash as there is no `downcase` for nil.

Comment: I implemented your change, though now when I login, I get the following error message: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<SessionsController:0x007f0485fbf190> for this line:   if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password]) - technically, isn't user now defined with the change you made in that line?

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, you'll have to change each occurrence of `user` to `@user` in your controller.

Comment: I did - see edits above - did I do it wrong (sorry for my newb-ness, lol)? Doing so gives me: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass <%= @user.email %>

Comment: Surely you'd have to set `@user` in the `users#show` action?

Answer (score 0):

It's because @user is nil,  try adding `@user = User.find(params[:id])` in your show action

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an oversight, but if you're *redirecting* to `@user`, I assume you'd need to invoke `@user` in `users#show`:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @user = User.find params[:id] #-> id will have been sent by redirect_to @user
   end
end
```

Comment: Already have this in my users_controller... the above controller posted is my session_controller.

Comment: Can you post your users controller please ?

Comment: Get `show` out of `private` in the `users_controller` and it should work for you

Comment: Ok, now even if I take the <% %> email line out of my show.html.erb file, I receive this error upon logging in: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<SessionsController:0x007f4254abea80> for line:  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])

Comment: Did you use `@user`?

Comment: niiiiice, can you explain what you did?